# Make a web page scrollable when resizing the browser

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am trying to understand how SingleChildScrollView, SizedBox and Expanded to make a screen that automatically create a scrollable page in Flutter Web. But I cannot really see a very good example in the web. I have tried with my code below but it always throw `overflow` error when I resize my browser. How can I make it scrollable?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<InkWell> menuList = [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Clicked");
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
              Text("ABC"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Scrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Row(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Column(children: menuList),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 1000,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    // child: SizedBox(width: 1000),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed width with `ConstrainedBox`, therefore it overflows, Also you you should provide separate context to call MediaQuery. And it is overflowing on horizontal direction. Change the   `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,`

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView( //extra for vertical case
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, //current issue was
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                // maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width cant have it here, if you like to resize put it on top level, before `SingleChildScrollView`
              ),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Row(children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 200,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      child: Column(children: menuList),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 1000,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      // child: SizedBox(width: 1000),
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```